# How can I show a Java calendar object in a JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a class with a Calendar (java.util.Calendar) attribute, and I am trying to show time and date in a JSP page but I get this error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Illegal pattern character 'b'.

JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${reports}" var="report" >
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${report.vehicleId}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${report.vehicleName}"/> </td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate value="${report.endTimeAndDate.time}  pattern="both" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${report.endTimeAndDate.time}" pattern="both"/> </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Java Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchreports")
public ModelAndView SearchReports (...parameters) {     
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<Report> reports = reportService.SearchReports(vehicleName, start,end);;

    map.put("reports", reports);
    return new ModelAndView("reportsview", map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify date pattern i.e. `pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"`.
Also you can read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm
(`"Both"` is value of attribute `type`).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you specifying `pattern='both'` twice? Also, you need a valid [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) format, which `both` is not.